# Конструктор с параметрами при использовании в emplace

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
  public:
    //A():a(0){ cout<<"const default"<<endl;}
    A(int _a):a(_a) {cout<<"const"<<endl;}
    A(const A & o) = delete;
    A & operator=(const A & o) = delete;
     ~A(){std::cout<<"dest"<<std::endl;}
     void show(){cout<<a<<endl;}
   private:
     int a;
 };

 std::map<int, A> m;

 void fun(int f, int d)
 {

   m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct ,std::forward_as_tuple(f)
            ,std::forward_as_tuple(d));
 }

 int main (int argc,char * argv[])
 {
   fun(4,7);
   m[4].show();
   m.erase(4);
   return 0;
 }
```

Ошибка в arm-gcc 8.3.1

```
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
     second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

Минимально воспроизводимый пример, шаблон tuple запрашивает конструктор без параметров, при добавлении конструктора без параметров , все работает корректно , но конструктор без параметров даже не вызывается.

Как корректно избавится от конструктора без параметров ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map::operator []` создает элемент с запрошенным индексом при его отсутствии используя конструктор по-умолчанию. Соответственно необходимо использовать метод `std::map::find`.

Comment: Используя std::map::find будет гарантировано использоваться конструктор без параметров , А конструктор без параметров совсем не нужен. от этого конструктора хотелось бы избавится.

Comment: @Yaroslav Все как раз же наоборот - при использовании find конструктор без параметров никогда использоваться не будет.

Comment: Вроде разобрался конструктор нужен std::map::[]